# How do I pass a counter into a component's function?

Tags: reactjs

Learning react here and doing the tic-tac-toe intro here: `https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe`.

I'm trying to understand why my code isn't working. I'm on the `https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe#completing-the-game` portion, where you add components like:

`<Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} />`

I'm trying to take a slightly different approach and create the squares programmatically, like so:

```
export default function Board() {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));

  function handleClick(i) {
    const nextSquares = squares.slice();
    nextSquares[i] = "X";
    setSquares(nextSquares);
  }

  var boardRows = [];
  var counter = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var boardSquares = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      boardSquares.push(<Square value={squares[counter]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(i)} />);
      counter ++;
    }

    boardRows.push(<div className="board-row"> {boardSquares} </div>);
  }

  return boardRows;
}
```

The problem is, the `handleClick(i)` is using 9, since that's the final value of my counter. Is there a way to have the function "save" the value that will be passed in on the click? Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: The easiest change to make is to use `let` instead of `var` in your loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems

1. The `i` you are passing in is only `0`~`2` due to its using the counter from the outer loop. Although it's not what you are asking, the next one will answer your answer
2. Because as Andy suggested in the comment, values that are declared with `var` are available throughout the function (in this case `Board`), so `i` will always be the last value at the end of the loop. You could fix that by declaring with `let` but that doesn't completely solve your problem, which leads to the next problem...
3. The value you are passing in not only is available throughout the function `Board`, but is not accurate. The easiest way to properly pass the value would be to define a value right before you pass it. In 95% of the cases, `const` is your best bet. Below is the proper fix --

```
  var boardRows = []
  var counter = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var boardSquares = []
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      const key = (i *3) + j /* declare const value here */
      boardSquares.push(
        <Square
          key={key}
          value={squares[counter]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(key)}
        />
      )
      counter++
    }

    boardRows.push(<div className="board-row"> {boardSquares} </div>)
  }
```

The code here not only answers your question, and also fixes the bug where the square you are clicking isn't aligned with what it is intended.

`const` value is block scope, and isn't mutatable, making it extra safe as a disposable value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks so much! This makes a lot of sense.